# Do event notifications get lost during lambda function update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a Lambda function that listens to S3 create requests. If I update the function, is there a brief amount of time where I am losing S3 notifications or do events continue to be served by the old version of the function?

If they are being lost, is there a recommended way to deal with the transition so events don't get lost?

Comment: I doubt there's any specific statement on the behavior here, but I would not expect you to have to do anything. There is always *some* version of the code available for Lambda to load, whether it's the previous version or the new version.

Answer (score 3):

The old version continues to run until the new version is up. No traffic/requests will be lost. Multiple lambda are stored allowing you to rollback.

When a function update request is made (even without a specific function version) an alias is created with an ARN and deployed then `$LATEST` is swapped to point to the new version.

A point of interest: You can actually slowly migrate your new lambda over with [Traffic Shifting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-traffic-shifting-using-aliases.html) Allowing you to monitor your new function with a subset of production traffic until you gain confidence to roll it out all the way.